# What kind of people will be alive on the last day of earth before the blowing of the trumpet?

Tags: sunni, shiism, shia-sunni, day-of-judgement

Do any sources from Shia make comments about the condition of people before the blowing of the trumpet.

I have failed to find anything on Al Islam about the kind of people alive at that time.

Why I am asking this is because as per Twelver belief the earth doesn't see a day without an imam.

> محمد بن الحسين عن الحسن بن محبوب عن العلاء عن عبد الله بن ابى يعفور عن ابى عبد الله عليه السلام قال كان على بن ابى طالب عليه السلام عالم هذه الامة والعلم يتوارث وليس يمضى منا احد حتى يرى من ولده من يعلم علمه ولا تبقى الارض يوما بغير امام منا تفزع إليه الامة قلت يكون امامان قال لا الا واحدهما صامت لا يتكلم حتى يمضى الاول. (Basa'iru d-Darajat of as-Safar al-Qumi)
>
> Abdu l-Lah ibn Abi Ya'fur said that Abu Abdi l-Lah (Jafaru s-Sadiq) said: "Ali ibn Abi Talib was the knowledgeable Imam of this Ummah and the knowledge is inherited. Not one of us passes away until he sees a son who learns his knowledge, and the Earth doesn't last for a day without an Imam from us, with the Ummah seeking refuge towards him

So the doubt arises. The last twelver imam comes to finish oppression. However per Sunni belief the oppression before the blowing of the trumpet is the worst kind.

Answer (score 0):

As per Sunni sources, we have only information on the life of Imam Mehdi till Prophet Isa returns. Thereafter, there is no mention of him even during the trial of Gog & Magog.

It is known that Isa will die way before the Trumpet is blown as is also known that a cool wind from Yemen will take the life of each believer leaving back only the Kafirs to inhabit the world. They will be among the most lewd & rude people on have lived on earth.

If you analyze the extract you have provided:

> ... and the Earth doesn't last for a day without an Imam from us,
> ***with the Ummah seeking refuge towards him***

Since the Ummah of believers would have perished before the blowing of the Trumpet, there is no contradiction here.

To summarize, it can inferred that Imam Mehdi will die during the lifetime of Prophet Isa & the worst of people will inhabit the planet when the trumpet is blown.

Comment: I was looking for twlever point of view. The tags point. I'm sorry for any confusion

Comment: Additionally from day one there is imam for humans. Adam being first imam as per twelvers

Comment: Twelvers belief points to that imam must be present always everyday. Humans are not without imam

Comment: @IbnKaleemullah Pardon my ignorance but what are the sources of information for a "Twelver" ? Do they supersede the Quran and the Sahih Hadiths or do they supplement them?